# Remove lines in a text file (Calls)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Those are calls times, so is expected than any call takes more than 2 secs or less than 0.5 secs(mostly is between 0.800 or 1.900 max.)I have a problem trying to find a script to delete some lines, here is an example:

```
06:28:30.259    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:28:54.191    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:28:55.596    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:29:19.251    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:29:20.042    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:29:20.566    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:29:42.900    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:29:44.268    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:30:08.146    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:30:09.530    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:30:31.925    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:30:33.228    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:30:56.178    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
```

The goal is obtain this result:

```
06:28:54.191    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:28:55.596    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:29:19.251    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:29:20.566    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:29:42.900    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:29:44.268    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:30:08.146    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:30:09.530    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:30:31.925    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:30:33.228    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
```

Comments:

The first message should be "+++PTT Press" always and the latest should be "FloorStatus: Granted"
Line 5 should be deleted because it does not have sense, a call setup should be (really) between 0.800 ms to 1.9 secs so less then 0.5xx ms is not so realistic so that line should be removed.

Could someone give me some tips please to move forward, I dont expect somebody solve this because it's a bit tricky. I've been working using some other scripts (bash) which I found here in this website but they dont fit to this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit newbie yet.

Comment: What is the exact logic behind "does not have sense"? Which lines do you want to remove? Why?

Comment: Any pair of lines "+++PTT Press xxxx" and "FloorStatus: Granted" are allocated for a call so for example in the latest pair of lines:
     06:30:31.925    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
     06:30:33.228    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error

The time for the call setup is 1.303

Comment: If we substract the times between the lines 6th and 5th the time is 0.5xxms so that is so fast. An avergae for a call setup is 0.800ms to 1.9ms. So that is why that line should be deleted. If you substract the times in the lines 6th and 4th you'll obtain 1.3xx ms and is whithin the average (0.800 - 1.900) ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little bit ugly (maybe you want to use awk or perl):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=calls.txt

## remove first line if it contains "Granted"/last line "+++PTT"
head -n 1 ${FILE} | grep -q Granted && sed -i '1d' ${FILE}
tail -n 1 ${FILE} | grep -q +++PTT && sed -i '$d' ${FILE}

## remove duplicated Granted entries
tac ${FILE} > ${FILE}.tac
sed -i '$!N; /^.*\(FloorStatus\).*\n.*\1.*$/!P; D' ${FILE}.tac
tac ${FILE}.tac > ${FILE}

LASTTIME=0

while read line ; do
  ## is line empty?
  if [ ! -z "${line}" ] ; then

    ## fetch times
    T=$(echo ${line} | cut -d " " -f 1)
    echo ${line} | grep -q +++PTT
    P=$?
    echo ${line} | grep -q Granted
    G=$?

    ## create timestamp
    #TSTAMP=$(date -d "${T}" +'%s%N')
    H=$(expr $(echo ${T} | cut -d : -f 1) \* 3600)
    M=$(expr $(echo ${T} | cut -d : -f 2) \* 60)
    S=$(echo ${T} | cut -d : -f 3 | sed 's#\.##g')
    TSTAMP=$(expr ${H} \+ ${M})
    TSTAMP=$(expr ${TSTAMP} \+ ${S})

    ## calculate diff
    D=$(expr ${TSTAMP} \- ${LASTTIME})

    ## less than threshold?
    #if [ ${D} -lt 800000000 ] ; then
    if [ ${D} -lt 800 -a ${P} -ne 0 ] ; then
      ## remove current call
      sed -i '/^'${T}'/d' ${FILE}
    fi
    LASTTIME=${TSTAMP}
  fi
done < ${FILE}

## remove duplicated +++PTT entries
tac ${FILE} > ${FILE}.tac
sed -i '$!N; /^.*\(+++PTT\).*\n.*\1.*$/!P; D' ${FILE}.tac
tac ${FILE}.tac > ${FILE}
```

Comment: ./example.sh: line 16: [: -: integer expression expected
date: invalid date `06:30:33.228'
./example.sh: line 16: [: -: integer expression expected
date: invalid date `06:30:56.178'

I got this error, but dunno why because operator is well declared..

Comment: BTW, is not matter what I might use, I'll be forever grateful to anyone for help me.

Comment: Hard to say, but I think so, how can I verify it? (I'm sry, im a rockie yet)

Comment: No, i think it doesn't work because the script can't read the ms time.

Comment: @Martin_911 My question was: Do you get `1328074233288000000` if you enter `date -d "06:30:33.288" +'%s%N'` in your bash?

Comment: yes, but I got that outcome deleting miliseconds (06:30:33 instead of 06:30:33.288) in whole the times.

Comment: Do you use GNU date? (Maybe "%N" is not known by any other date.) `date --version`

Comment: Yes, I'm using GNU date (GNU/Linux)

Comment: @Martin Thats very strange. What is the output of `date -d "06:30:33.288" +'%N'`? (should be 288000000)

Comment: Oh, I really sry I didn't understand your first question. BTW when I place this command    date -d "06:30:33.288" +'%s%N' I have this outcome    date: invalid date `06:30:33.288'.

Comment: And also I have this outcome when I place    date --version:
date (coreutils) 5.2.1
Written by David MacKenzie.

Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: @Martin_911 Maybe you affected by a bug after rewrite of date's parser (a similar problem http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?11687). My date is part of coreutils 8.5. I edited my answer and show an approach to avoid using date.

Comment: It's very good really but in the example the first line should be deleted because the first line always should be "+++PTT", what can I add to script to delete the first arrow when it starts whith "FloorStatus: Granted"?

Comment: @Martin_911 `head -n 1 ${FILE} | grep -q Granted && sed -i '1d' ${FILE}` (see my edited answer)

Comment: when I run the script (last edited script) I see it finish in `+++PTT` so that last line should be delete too. To do that should I add this line? `tail -n 1 ${FILE} | grep -q +++PTT && sed -i '1d' ${FILE}`

Comment: @Martin_911 `sed -i '$d' ${FILE}`

Comment: Outcome:
`06:28:54.191    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:28:55.596    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:29:42.900    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:29:44.268    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:30:09.530    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error
06:30:31.925    qchatmgr_pal.c  197     E       +++PTT Press    Call Manager/Error
06:30:33.228    *InCallForm.c   934     E       FloorStatus: Granted    Legacy/Error`

Comment: @Martin_911 Answer edited. Please note this was my last commit to this topic.

Comment: I really appreciate your time to perform this.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you can use a code like this:

```
    while read FirstField SecondField ThirdField ForthFiled FifthField SeventhField
    do
    #you have your Values of a line in this seven variables

    done < yourfilename
```

this file will read all your file and save values of time in `FirstField` and the second field like *InCallForm.c in the `SecondField` and etc.
so you can do every thing with your file in this while loop.
if you didn't understand I can tell more...

Comment: I got the idea but I should handle almost 800 or 10000 lines :S

Comment: Ok, but whats wrong with lots of lines? it's a loop and will read your file line by line.